# Using Filter Query on multivalued param in Solr , duplicated docs in response

Tags: solr

I receive strange problem with using fq param in requests to Solr

```
curl '127.0.0.1:8080/solr/app/select?rows=0&start=0&q=app+AND+categoryId:20'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">1</int>
<lst name="params"><str name="start">0</str><str name="q">app AND categoryId:20</str>
<str name="rows">0</str></lst></lst>
<result name="response" numFound="42236" start="0"></result>
</response>
```

and second request

```
curl '127.0.0.1:8080/solr/app/select?rows=0&start=0&q=app+AND+categoryId:20&fq=categoryId:20'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">1</int>
<lst name="params"><str name="start">0</str><str name="q">app AND categoryId:20</str>
<str name="fq">categoryId:20</str><str name="rows">0</str></lst></lst>
<result name="response" numFound="69480" start="0"></result>
</response>
```

Different just in using addition param &fq=categoryId:20 , but as you can see this filter also present in main query and must have no affect on result.

I checked response and found a lot of duplicates in first request.

also tags show 42236 docs for categoryId=20,

So why query with &fq=categoryId:20  return so lot(and duplicates) docs ? 
P.S. all other categories works correct.

part of scheme:

```
    <field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
    <field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
    <field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" required="true"/>
    <field name="categoryId" type="int" indexed="true" stored="false" required="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="tags" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="type" type="int" indexed="true" stored="false" required="true"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be a Facet Caching deleted records issue. Check [SOLR-3793](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3793)

Comment: Thanks a lot, you right. Looks like I need wait main release which must include this fix.  As temporary solution often "commit&optimize" launched manually help with this